# NHaml - still active?

Tags: nhaml

I accidentally stumbled across NHaml and really like what I have seen of it. However, checking the blogs of the authors and Google group reveals that there doesn't seem to be much happening.

Is it worth investing time in NHaml - is it going forward actively? If anyone can point me to the centre of activity for NHaml or at least let me know the "state of play", I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Nhaml is still active. Although Andrew is no longer active in its developement.

It has also moved out of MVCContrib and is now a project on Google code http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/

The google group is reasonably active
http://groups.google.com/group/nhaml-users/about

Not sure if lack of blogs posts means a project is stagnating?

It is probably better to look at the 
[issue list](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/issues/list?can=1&q=&sort=-modified&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary+Modified&cells=tiles) or the 
[checkin list](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/source/list)

And we are always happy to take contributions

Answer (score 1):

[Russell Allen](http://www.russellallen.info/) is actively developing NHaml with the goal of integrating it into [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) as a view engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using NHAML for about 9 months on an ASP.NET MVC project. I like it a lot but I think you may want to consider the Spark View Engine. While I believe NHAML is still an active project, it is not very well documented. Spark is very well documented and has a series of tutorials by developers. I will be using Spark in most of my projects in the future

You can check out the SparkViewEngine at [link text](http://sparkviewengine.com/) .